# Setting gmail's email category (social, promotion) through IMAP

Tags: email, gmail, imap, google-schemas

I am implementing an email client and would like to allow the user move email across "Category" e.g. from "Primary" to "Social".
How to do that through IMAP command or Gmail IMAP extension?

Comment: Read some docs about it first and try out implementing it in code and show us your code

Comment: I am using javamail in Android. I am able to move messages across folder base on RFC3501 and fetch label base on https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions
But I can't find any docs about the "category" in gmail.
So any suggestion on related docs will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe this functionality is exposed through IMAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail's [category labels](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3055016?hl=en) aren't exposed in the IMAP interface, but they are available in the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels).